# Rxjs filter split string observable with separator

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, rxjs, angular-pipe

I have to split a string with a comma separator into an observable for an autocomplete service.

The string is something like that :

```
nom_commune = Ambarès,ambares,Ambares,ambarès
```

I would like to get the first value of the string : `Ambarès`

I tried to split into the observable but I have this error:

> Property 'split' does not exist on type 'boolean'.

```typescript
    return this.http.get<IUserResponse>('https://tu.com/agriobs-codeigniter/index.php/structure/get_area/17').pipe(
      map((response: IUserResponse) => {
        response.results = response.results
          .map(user => new User(user.id_commune, user.nom_commune))
          .filter(user => user.nom_commune.includes(filter.name).split(",")[0])
         // console.log(response.results[0].nom_commune.split(",")[0]);
        return response; 
      })  
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting that error because of the order of your operations

```
user.nom_commune.includes(filter.name).split(",")[0])
```

this translates to

1. return boolean if `user.nom_commune` includes `filter.name`
2. then you are trying to split the value returned from this operations.
3. the value returned from the previous operation being a boolean, doesn't support `split`

this is why you are getting the error.

If I had to guess you probably want to change the sequence of your operations to

```
user.nom_commune.split(",").includes(filter.name)
```

but that's just a guess based on the code you shared so far.

UPDATE Based on OP comments

```
return response.results
  .map(user => new User(user.id_commune, user.nom_commune))
  .filter(user => user.nom_commune.includes(filter.name))
  .map( user => user.nom_commune.split(",")[0])
```

Comment: I did that but it doesn't split at all  :  user.nom_commune.split(",")[0].includes(filter.name). I can only split the response !

Comment: filter return a boolean ?

Comment: the `includes` operator returns a boolean. [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: console.log(user.nom_commune.split(",")[0].includes(filter.name)) return a boolean but in that case it should return the string Ambarès ?

Comment: is the goal you are trying to achieve to have `response.results` be an array of the first values in the `user` object?

Comment: In fact the goal is to have the response.results an array with the first values of nom_commune

Comment: I've updated the answer to include what you're looking for. the issue is that you were trying to combine `filter` and `map` on the results. first you `filter` your response based on if the value contain a string, then you `map` that filtered lists to the first value of the nom_commune

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes i missed a step !